# Memory, FSB, Overclocking and Heat Issues

Tags: overclocking, cooling

I've read somewhere on the net that my FSB-to-DRAM Ratio should be 1:1 to maximize performance, so I decided to try it out.

Comp Specs: 
* Intel Q8200 2.33Ghz Stock 
* Transcend aXeRam DDR2-1066+ 4gb Kit 
* Ion2 700w PSU 
* Stock Cooling

The default values at bios looked like this: 
* FSB Freq 200Mhz 
* Mem Clock DDR2-667Mhz

First, I changed the FSB Freq to 533Mhz since my ram said that it's should run fine at 1066Mhz.. My CPU Clock shot to 3.1Ghz (!!) and a bios warning told me that my CPU is running a bit too hot :( I looked around the net and found this tool called realtemp.exe, ran it and my Idle Temp is at 65c (at 1~5% CPU Usage).. When I try to run games (Prototype, to be specific), the screen blacks out (no BSOD) and computer restarts :'(

So, I changed it to default values again :D and went here to ask for some advice on how to continue.. I know that there's a lot of resources on the web about this kind of stuff, but I can't make heads or tails about TCase, TJ Max, JEDEC (wtf?), CAS#, RAS#, TRAS# (trash?) and some other stuff that the pros were talking about so uhm...

help? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 1:1. Memory performance is kind of irrelevant (within reason) for most tasks, so just try **increasing your FSB by a smaller amount this time**.

Also, use stability testing tools rather than games, it's faster and simpler.

Foremost among those is [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/); if your system can survive Prime95 for an hour, it's very likely to be stable in CPU and memory.

So in summary

- make smaller changes
- test after each small change
- increase if things are stable

Comment: So you don't need to run it for a whole day to make sure things are stable?

Comment: I said "very likely" -- if you want 100% likely, let it run overnight.